# Relating Leads to Contacts (Person Accounts actually)?

Tags: reporting, administration

Has anyone ever tackled trying to do this?

**Creating a relationship from Lead to Person Account (or even Contact) so that you could (especially with the Joined Report option now available) access data from Lead to PersonAccount to Opportunity (or Case)**

Even if it's a plugin from App Exchange, I'd be willing to try it.  I've looked at this randomly a few times in the past year, and it's frustrating that you've got the Converted ID reference sitting there, but not able to use it (nevermind the complexity of merged Accounts where only one reference to Lead could exist after the fact, among other things).

If anyone has any insight on magic they've done along these lines, I'd love to hear it.  We're trying to avoid having to pay a ton of money for items such as *GoodData* which could do "some forms" of linkage between Lead and PersonAccount / Contact.

Comment: I appreciate the upvotes - I didn't want to find that people thought this was a superficial or unworthy Question.  Person Accounts aside (they're annoying enough with their various quirks), it's really frustrating that a relationship from Lead to it's converted record is not a de-facto SOP in SF.  :-P

Comment: Where does Converted Id fall short? I haven't tried to use it much with PA but am interested in investigating.

Comment: It's just an ID.  It does not establish a relationship between Lead and Account.  :-/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Our solution ended up being external reporting.

Namely...

We have Salesforce mirrored constantly to PostgreSQL.
We have CopyStorm by CapStorm mirroring our SF data frequently.
We have MicroStrategy BI/Reporting/Analytical tools pointed at PSQL.

We can relate any data to any data using any key we choose.  So the converted Lead ID, with the PersonAccount, with the Opp, etc, is all possible.

Note:  MicroStrategy is not for the faint of heart, administration or development wise.

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to write a trigger on lead (Before Update) and check to see if the lead is converted, then using a custom lookup field on the lead object populate it with the ID of the PersonAccount?

I know you cannot do it once it has been updated to converted but maybe in the before trigger you could....

Comment: Triggers on Lead conversion need to be handled in AFTER UPDATE, otherwise the Lead isn't converted, but the idea is sound. It would create the relationship that could be used in reporting.